# Neo4j with Node.js inserting array within array

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I'm trying to create some nodes and connections in a Neo4j database using node.js. I'm messing around with some of the tutorials and trying to modify them. I'm a Noob to Nodes. In this situation, I have an array of objects that I'm parsing over to populate the database with. Within each object, there are `experiences` arrays. I keep getting the error;

> Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
>   inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
>   promise which was not handled with .catch()

I think the error is related to the loop `experiences.forEach`. It's a loop within the loop. I'm not sure how I can overcome this.

```
// Create a person node
function addPerson(tx, name) {
  return tx.run("MERGE (a:Person {name: $name})", { name: name });
}

// Create a position node
async function addPosition(tx, name) {
  return tx.run("CREATE (a:Position {name: $name})", { name: name });
}

// Create an employment relationship to a pre-existing Person node.
// This relies on the person first having been created.
function addPositionConnection(tx, personName, positionTitle) {
  return tx.run(
    "MATCH (person:Person {name: $personName}) " + "MATCH (position:Position {name: $positionTitle}) " + "CREATE (person)-[:HAS_POSITION]->(position)",
    {
      personName: personName,
      positionTitle: positionTitle
    }
  );
}

(async function neo4jInsertData() {
  try {
    const profiles = [
      {
        userProfile: {
          fullName: "Test name 1"
        },
        experiences: [
          {
            title: "CEO"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        userProfile: {
          fullName: "Test name 2"
        },
        experiences: [
          {
            title: "CTO"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    for (var x = 0; x < profiles.length; x++) {
      const name = profiles[x].userProfile.fullName;
      const experiences = profiles[x].experiences;

      const session1 = driver.session(neo4j.WRITE);

      const first = session1
        .writeTransaction(tx => addPerson(tx, name))
        .then(tx => {
          try {
            experiences.forEach((tx, experience, index) => {
              addPosition(tx, experience.title).then(() => addPositionConnection(tx, name, experience.title));
            });
          } catch (err) {
            console.log("err", err);
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("closing");

          return session1.close();
        });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("there is an error", err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addPosition` function is annotated with `async`, so `addPosition` will return a promise that could be asynchronously rejected (e.g., if its `tx.run` call throws an exception).

The error message you got is saying that the promise returned by your `addPosition` invocation (which has a `then` block) was rejected, but since the promise had no `catch` block the rejection could not be handled.

One way to solve this is to annotate the `addPosition` invocation using `await`, which would convert any promise rejection into a thrown exception.